# Debugging Program Keeps Sending Emails After Exit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, events, error-handling

I have the below code which I use as part of a program which reads some event logs.

After stepping through the code this morning to test something out, I keep getting error messages emailed to me:

> EventLogHelper error occurred in QueryEvents
>
> Exception: The RPC server is unavailable
>
> User:
>
> Client: D7-089

The process is not running on my machine, and I only stepped through the method in question once or twice. However The messages just keep coming. The space of time between each message seems to vary, and I have received at least 15 now.

How is this possible? I feel that if the program is sending me emails, it must be executing somewhere, but I cannot see it in the `Processes` tab in `Task Manager`, and I tried ending all `Visual Studio` related processes without any joy.

---

I restarted the PC on which VS was running, but I am still receiving the emails.

---

#### Main()

```
public static void Main()
{
    var eh = new EventLogHelper();
    var eventFired = eh.CheckEvents();
}
```

## EventLogHelper.cs

```
public readonly string PcName;
private readonly int Timespan;
private readonly string Filter;
private static EventLogSession Session;

/// <summary>
/// ctor
/// </summary>
public EventLogHelper()
{
    Timespan = 30000; // 30 seconds
    PcName = "D7-089"; // This is usually "Environment.MachineName", but specified it here for testing
    Filter = $"*[System[(EventID='5061' or EventID='5058') and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= {Timespan}]]]";
}
```

#### CheckEvents

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks the event logs for remote pc and returns true if any of the events we are interested in fired
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool CheckEvents()
{
    var query = BuildQuery(PcName, Filter);
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        var logs = QueryEvents(query);
        var events = ReadLogs(logs);

        if (events > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    return false;
}
```

#### BuildQuery

```
/// <summary>
/// Builds an EventLogQuery for the given pcname and filter. This should be set up with a user who has admin rights
/// </summary>bh
private static EventLogQuery BuildQuery(string pcName, string filter)
{
    try
    {
        using (var pw = GetPassword())
        {
            Session = new EventLogSession(
            pcName,
            "DOMAIN",
            "USER",
            pw,
            SessionAuthentication.Default);
        }

        return new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName, filter)
            { Session = Session };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Email.Send($"EventLogHelper error occurred in BuildQuery \n\n Exception: {ex.Message} \n\n User: {Program.UserName} \n\n Client: {pcName}");
        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### QueryEvents

This is where the error is occurring. I stepped through this method 2 times **at most** and as I type this question I am still getting error emails through.

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute the given EventLogQuery
/// </summary>
private EventLogReader QueryEvents(EventLogQuery query)
{
    try
    {
        return new EventLogReader(query);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Email.Send($"EventLogHelper error occurred in QueryEvents \n\n Exception: {ex.Message} \n\n User: {Program.UserName} \n\n Client: {PcName}");
        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### ReadLogs

```
/// <summary>
/// Read the given EventLogReader and return the amount of events that match the IDs we are looking for
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logReader"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private int ReadLogs(EventLogReader logReader)
{
    var count5058 = 0;
    var count5061 = 0;
    EventRecord entry;

    try
    {
        while ((entry = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
        {

            if (entry.Id == 5058)
            {
                count5058++;
            }
            else
            {
                count5061++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Email.Send($"EventLogHelper error occurred in ReadLogs \n\n Exception: {ex.Message} \n\n User: {Program.UserName} \n\n Client: {PcName}");
        Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }

    return count5058 + count5061;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was being caused by a stupid mistake on my part.

This program has a Post-Build Event which is called with:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release ("$(ProjectDir)PostBuildRelease.bat" "$(TargetDir)" @(VersionNumber) "$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName)")
```

So it only runs when VS build configuration is set to `Release`.

`PostBuildRelease.bat` simply copies the resuling assembly to the live location, ready for users to have copied to their desktops at logon.

- Whilst testing my app, I foolishly edited the source code to query a specific PC, and then stepped through the code.
- However, the build configuration was set to `Release`, So once the assembly was built ready to be debugged, it was automatically copied into the live executable location and therefore also copied to user's desktops at logon.
- If the code is run with a hard-coded `PcName` where that PC is not the current machine, the event query appears to fail with the above error message.
- So all of the emails I receiving were being sent out because the program was actually being executed on user PCs. However because `PcName` was hard-coded in, it always looked like it was coming from my instance of the program!

The lesson here is to always be aware of which build configuration is currently selected, especially if a Post-Build event is specified.

Comment: Since this question has been resolved, please mark it as the answer, so it would be helpful for other community members who meet the same issue, thanks for your sharing:)